# PHP Array shows only the last array item

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach loop ($product_image) and an array ($newProductData), what I am trying to do is put the foreach content ($mediagalleryURLs) into the $newProductData array, when I print_r $newProductData, the the output shows only the last foreach element as $newProductData['media_gallery'] value, not the full elements, here is the code:

```
<?php
...

$resimURLNew = (string) $item->xpath('images/image[@main=1]')[0];

foreach($item->images->image as $product_image) {
    $mediagalleryURLs = $product_image.';';
    $mediagalleryURLs = rtrim($mediagalleryURLs, ';');
}

$newProductData = array(
    'sku'               => (string) $item->id,
    'barcode'           => (string) $item->barcode
);

$newProductData['image']       = (string) $resimURLNew;
$newProductData['small_image'] = (string) $resimURLNew;
$newProductData['thumbnail']   = (string) $resimURLNew;
$newProductData['media_gallery']   = $mediagalleryURLs;

...
?>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the `$mediagalleryURLs ` on each iteration of the foreach loop.

Comment: Should @mediagalleryURLs be an Array or a semicolon separated string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to append the Urls:

```
foreach($item->images->image as $product_image) {
    $mediagalleryURLs .= rtrim($product_image) . ';';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the variable when you should be appending elements to your array:

```
$mediagalleryURLs = array();
foreach($item->images->image as $product_image) {
    $mediagalleryURLs[] = rtrim($product_image.';', ';');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 $newProductData = array(
    'sku'               => (string) $item->id,
     'barcode'           => (string) $item->barcode
);

foreach($item->images->image as $product_image) {
    $mediagalleryURLs = $product_image.';';
    $mediagalleryURLs = rtrim($mediagalleryURLs, ';');
    $newProductData['media_gallery']   = $mediagalleryURLs;
 }

 $newProductData['image']       = (string) $resimURLNew;
 $newProductData['small_image'] = (string) $resimURLNew;
 $newProductData['thumbnail']   = (string) $resimURLNew;
```